# Using C, one code, multiple headers if/else?

Tags: c, if-statement, header

I have one piece of code that I can use for the same function on different sets of data which are defined in different header files . These header files may have the same variable defined differently.

I can pass a parameter to the code when I call it to specify which dataset I want to perform the function on.

What I would like to do is pass this parameter to the code where if the parameter equals X then I use headerX, or if parameter equals Y I use headerY.

It is my understanding that header files must be included before MAIN.  Is it possible to include the header file after MAIN so that I can write an if/else statement to determine which header file I am calling?

If I can't do that then please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use #ifdef - blocks to determine which data set you'd want to use before compiling. But if you wanted a different data set, you would need to change (recompile) the executable by changing that define.

Otherwise you would need to compile in C++ as straight C does not support overloaded functions.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you just can't. You may be able to include headers before hand based on a condition. Just use #if-def blocks at the top of the file.

But you can't include it like if else:

**This is WRONG**

```
if(x == 1)
    #include "header1.h"
else
    #include "header2.h"
```

**But you can do this at the top of the file:**

```
#if SYSTEM_1
    #include "system_1.h"
#elif SYSTEM_2
    #include "system_2.h"
#elif SYSTEM_3
    #include "system_3.h"
#endif
```

Or you could just use C++ which does support overloaded functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple metaprogramming by using the macro preprocessing phase. Create a "interface_myFunc.h" with something like

```
#define FUNCNAME(T) myFunc_ ## T

void FUNCNAME(theType)(theType t);
```

Create a "implement_myFunc.h" file with something like

```
void FUNCNAME(theType)(theType t) {
 // do something with t
}
```

and then include this file in another file  "myFunc.h"

```
#define theType toto
#include "interface_myFunc.h"
#undef theType toto

#define theType tutu
#include "interface_myFunc.h"
#undef theType tutu
```

and similar for the definitions, "myFunc.c"

```
#define theType toto
#include "implement_myFunc.h"
#undef theType toto

#define theType tutu
#include "implement_myFunc.h"
#undef theType tutu
```

Modern C, C11, also has ways to create a common interface for all these functions that you create by so-called type generic macros:

```
#define myFunc(X)              \
_Generic((X),                  \
         toto: FUNCNAME(toto), \
         tutu: FUNCNAME(tutu)  \
)(X)
```